# tensorflow reading data from database

Tags: python, database, tensorflow, bigdata

I am new to tensorflow. I have a large amount of data in my data base and I want a way to train a tensorflow model on the data. I understand how to do this if I was writing the data to a csv file and then reading the data from csv. 
But how do I do this directly from the data base. I can connect to the database from my script(python) and run an SQL query to retrieve the data but if I want to learn in batches or epochs and mix the data?
Also the data is too big to hold in memory all at once.
any tips on where to start?
Thank you

Comment: Is anything preventing you from querying the database multiple times? Why can't you just run select statements with a limit of whatever size makes sense in your case, and then create minibatches from your returned rows? Then once you've run SGD steps on each of your rows, run another query and create more minibatches. Maybe I'm missing something about what difficulty you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Let's reiterate the problem :

- it is impossible to load all the data into memory (even if the data is trimmed of all unneeded meta data)
- it is not possible (for technical or policy reasons) to first query the database then save the results to disk as a csv file then work with the csv file.

If we could implement either of the above then we wouldn't have the problem.  We are stuck with querying the database somehow and we want to:

- get the data in smallish chunks

Well, that is easy enough!  Let's say that our database has a primary key that is numeric.  Simply decide how many chunks you want the data in and use a function like modulus

```
# for 7 batches
key % 7 == 0 gets you the first batch
key % 7 == 1 gets you the second batch
... etc
```

Okay, so you want to add another requirement

- get the data in **random** smallish chunks

Well, that's not too difficult.  Let's just change pick 2 random numbers X (preferably a prime number) and Y (less than the number of batches) and do the same thing but like so

```
# for 7 batches
( key * X + Y ) % 7 == 0 gets you the first batch
( key * X + Y ) % 7 == 1 gets you the second batch
... etc
```

You don't have a list of primes handy?  No problem, [just get a whole bunch](https://web.archive.org/web/20171126232119/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.prime.num.html) and pick one at random.

For the next epoch use a different X and Y and you'll get different batches.